# How to fix problem with start Nx react+express

Tags: reactjs, express, monorepo, nx-workspace

[webpack-dev-server] [HPM] Error occurred while proxying request localhost:4200/api to http://localhost:3333/ [ECONNREFUSED] (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)

I create nx app with react and express and when I tried to start app I had this problem

[image]

Answer (score 1):

npm run start is only running the react app, so in order to use both (react+express), if nx is not installed globally, add the line

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nx serve",
    "start-api": "nx serve api",
    "build": "nx build",
    "test": "nx test"
  },
```

just bellow "start": "nx serve", and run two consoles, in one you can run

```
npm run start
```

and in the other

```
npm run start-api
```

that way you will have both modules running and the error will disappear